# How to send customized response if the unauthroized credentials were provided in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

How to send customised response if the unauthorised credentials were provided in django rest.

```
class StockList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self,request):
         stocks = Stock.objects.all()
         serializer = StockSerializer(stocks,many=True)
         return Response({'user': serializer.data,'post': serializer.data})
    def post(self):
         pass
```

Here when I Hit url by invalid credentials i get 401 error on development server.
But i want to send customised response on client using json. 
any suggestions are welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to send a custom response for all 401 errors?

Comment: @arpit solanki yes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom exception handler to customized response of api exception.

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

    if response.status_code == 401:
        response.data['some_message'] = "Some custom message"

    return response
```

Then in setting.py you have to add your custom error handler

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.path.to.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Refs: [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Comment: I saw that but could not figureout how to implement this in my code. So please manipulte this in my code

Comment: what you could not figure out. Put the code mention above in any file and give out its path in your settings.py file

Comment: did that but now showing valueerror as empty module name

Comment: what extension should be there .py ?

Comment: yeah it should be .py

Comment: then where to save that file

Comment: you can save it anywhere. Just make sure you give correct path in settings.py file

Comment: 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': '/mayuresh/shopcon/JsonApp/',
this is my path and file name is exception.py

Comment: you need to give path like `'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'shopcon.JsonApp.exception.custom_exception_handler'`

Comment: Could not import 'shopcon.JsonApp.exception.custom_exception_handler' for API setting 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER'. ImportError: No module named JsonApp.exception. error is showing now

Comment: are there `__init__.py` files in each of these directories ?

Comment: well there should be `__init__.py` if there isn't one already. @SachinKukreja

Comment: Only the directory structure will tell, then.